# Customizing Joomla blog listing page

Tags: joomla, blogs, overriding

I have to customize the layout of the blog listing page for a Joomla site. When I created an override for com_content in my Joomla instance all that was created was a file for the individual blog post. While I do need this, I also need to be able to customize the blog listing page(the index of all blog posts). How do I create an override for the listing page?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the blog listing page override is actually in the 'com_content -> category' folder. I now have access to the blog.php file.